# get att value from xml file php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i try to get some value from xml file and yhe value was i get is "0" all the time
this is my code:

```
    <?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("SwiftNess_21911904_1.xml")or die("Error: Cannot create object");
print_r((string)$xml->KoteretKovetz[0]->KOD-SHOLEACH);
```

?>

and this is the xml file:

```
    <Mimshak>
<KoteretKovetz>
<SUG-MIMSHAK>1</SUG-MIMSHAK>
<MISPAR-GIRSAT-XML>006</MISPAR-GIRSAT-XML>
<TAARICH-BITZUA>20171025155621</TAARICH-BITZUA>
<KOD-SVIVAT-AVODA>2</KOD-SVIVAT-AVODA>
<KIVUN-MIMSHAK-XML>4</KIVUN-MIMSHAK-XML>
<KOD-SHOLEACH>520024647</KOD-SHOLEACH>
<SHEM-SHOLEACH>כלל חברה לביטוח בע"מ</SHEM-SHOLEACH>
<KOD-MEZAHE-METAFEL>520024647</KOD-MEZAHE-METAFEL>
<SHEM-METAFEL>כלל חברה לביטוח בע"מ</SHEM-METAFEL>
<MEZAHE-HAAVARA>004000520024647CONSLTING006201710251556553252.DAT</MEZAHE-HAAVARA>
<MISPAR-HAKOVETZ>20171025155655520024647</MISPAR-HAKOVETZ>
</KoteretKovetz>
<YeshutYatzran>...</YeshutYatzran>
<ReshumatSgira>...</ReshumatSgira>
</Mimshak>
```

Comment: Check my answer, It seems to be the solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php):

> Accessing elements within an XML document that contain characters not
>   permitted under PHP's naming convention (e.g. **the hyphen**) can be
>   accomplished by **encapsulating the element name within braces and the
>   apostrophe**.

Therefore:

```
print_r((string)$xml->KoteretKovetz[0]->{'KOD-SHOLEACH'});
```

Comment: wrap `KOD-SHOLEACH` by quotes

Comment: Right,  missed that one